# Can't see internal hard drive on Chrome OS

Tags: hard-drive, google-chrome-os

I have 3 internal hard drive (1 SSD for my Windows installation and 2 for data) and 1 external hard drive
I have install Chrome OS from Brunch project into a external hard drive. And when i launch file in Chrome OS i can't see any of the 3 internal hard drive.
Please help me as the data is very important.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome OS system doesnt let you view any internal drives or partitions. The only thing you could do is to put the chromebook in developer mode (Just google How to put a chromebook in developer mode) and maybe you could find a way through there. The only thing is that youd have to reset everything on the chrome os partition to be able to boot to developer mode.